# How can I get [checkbox] mail tag values into a unordered list inside the email in CF7?

Tags: email, checkbox, tags, contact-form-7

[checkbox services one_label_element "DJ" "Live Dhol" "MC" "Intelligent Dancefloor Lighting" "Uplighting" "Pinspot Lighting"]<

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Smart Grid extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), it introduces mail tag filters, so you would do something like,

```
add_filter( 'cf7sg_mailtag_my-checkbox', 'filter_cf7_mailtag_my_checkbox', 10, 3);
function filter_cf7_mailtag_select_option($tag_replace, $submitted, $cf7_key){
  /*the $tag_replace string to change*/
  /*the $submitted an array containing all submitted fields*/
  /*the $cf7_key is a unique string key to identify your form, which you can find in your form table in the dashboard.*/
  if('my-form'==$cf7_key ){
    $tag_replace = '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($submitted['my-checkbox'] as $value){
      $tag_replace .= "<li>{$value}</li>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    $tag_replace .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $tag_replace;
}
```

The filter is customised for each mail tag, in this example I have a checkbox field called `my-checkbox`, the plugin create the custom filter and helper code.
Please view this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcC36e69-eM&list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW&index=6&t=1390s) to understand how to obtain the appropirate filter.